# Python doesn't restart the linux process properly

Tags: php, python, linux, process

I have a PHP project and I use Python to deploy it on the production server.

Here is the plan of deployment:

1. find new `php.ini` file (path is defined)
2. replace the current one with this file
3. restart PHP-FPM process via `os.system('service php-fastcgi restart')`, where php-fastcgi is the real name of process.

Python doesn't show any errors during the execution of the script, but PHP restarts with default configuration. When I'm attempting to restart it manually ( in Linux terminal ), it works perfectly and new `php.ini` configuration loads succesfully. Can you please explain this strange behaviour of my Python  script?

**UPDATE**

Here is the part of Python script.

```
    php_ini_path_replace = '/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini'
    php_ini_path_source = os.path.join(destination, 'production', 'config', 'main-php.ini')

    try:        # Read source file
        source_conf_file = open(php_ini_path_source, 'r')
        php_ini_lines = source_conf_file.readlines()
    except IOError:
        print('Something is wrong with source file')

    try:
        actual_conf_file = open(php_ini_path_replace, 'w')
        actual_conf_file.writelines( php_ini_lines )
        print('PHP CGI configuration was succesfully changed.\nDon\'t forget to restart the PHP')
    except IOError:
        print('Something is wrong with actual file. May be it\'s in use')

os.system('service php-fastcgi restart')
```

Comment: How about *posting* the actual script you're talking about?

Comment: Thanks! Python isn't my thing. Don't you need to clean up the file handle before rewriting the file? Maybe try getting an exclusive file lock? At least those would be the things I'd worry about in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`copyfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) instead of manually opening and closing files.

```
import shutil

php_ini_path_replace = '/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini'
php_ini_path_source = os.path.join(destination, 'production', 'config', 'main-php.ini')

try:
    shutil.copyfile(php_ini_path_source, php_ini_path_replace)
except (Error,IOError):
    print('Error copying the file')

os.system('service php-fastcgi restart')
```

Answer (score 1):

The data written by `writelines()` may remain in an in-proccess cache until the file is flushed (like in C).  Other processes started just afterwards may see an empty or partial file.  What you need to add is `source_conf_file.close()` when you're done writing it.  (It's an annoying issue because when the Python processes finishes, *then* the file is flushed and appears correct if you try to look at it afterwards.)

Comment: Thank you! Will try it in a bit

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better paste the return code or string from the shell cmd, it can help us find the root cause.

Some advise:

Do remember to close file handler. You can use `with`. like:

```
try:
    with open(php_ini_path_source, 'r') as source_conf_file:
        php_ini_lines = source_conf_file.readlines()
except IOError:
    print('Something is wrong with source file')
```